# uploading zip files to google cloud with command line gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

We have zip files created with Backup4All that we want to upload to GCP using the gsutil rsync command line tool.  I originally used drag/drop to see the current backups to GCP and they copied normally.  When I run the rsync command I get a long list of output lines.

```
Resuming upload for file://G:\BU4A\CVV backup\273_E001.zip
Catching up md5 for file://G:\BU4A\CVV backup\273_E001.zip...
/ [0 files][265.3 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
\ [0 files][266.3 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
| [0 files][268.6 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
- [0 files][270.9 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
\ [0 files][273.2 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
/ [0 files][276.1 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
- [0 files][278.9 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
| [0 files][281.8 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
/ [0 files][284.6 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
\ [0 files][287.4 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]
/ [0 files][290.3 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
- [0 files][293.1 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
| [0 files][295.9 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
/ [0 files][298.8 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
\ [0 files][301.6 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
/ [0 files][304.4 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
- [0 files][307.3 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
| [0 files][310.1 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
/ [0 files][313.0 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
\ [0 files][315.8 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
| [0 files][318.6 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
- [0 files][321.5 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
| [0 files][324.3 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
/ [0 files][327.1 MiB/ 10.0 GiB]    2.7 MiB/s
...
...
...
```

I am using

```
gsutil rsync -r "G:\BU4A\CVV backup" "gs://backup4all/CVV Backup"
```

to sync the files up to GCP.  Is this normal behavior?  Does this only happen to zip files?  It did not happen with database backup files I uploaded to another bucket.  I only want to copy the zip files to GCP.  The files inside the zips do not need to be compared as they will not change.  I have searched for documentation on uploading zip files but all I could find is instructions on creating gzips on the fly.

Comment: It is unclear what your actual question is. Can you clarify the question and problem more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

The output reads:
There was an interruption during transfering the files. The process tries to resume, where it was interrupted.

Anyway rsync checks (weither checking by checksum or by mtime) on file-level, not extracting zip files.

It seems to be a 10GiB upload. You are using the recursive option for the folder "G:\BU4A\CVV backup", "273_E001.zip" is one file inside this folder.

If you are really trying to upload 10GiB with a speed of 2.7MiB/s, those lines can be read as an alive-notification, the progress is simply written to stdout after a certain duration.

Comment: So is this output simply the same thing that updates the progress bar when using the web site to upload?

Comment: Not "the same" but yes it a way to show progress and that the process is still active and transferring something.